# Inverse of Inner join (Intersect) with multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

Hi I want to get **opposite** of intersect from two tables.

I have a sale table and purchase table. What I want to do is get all purchases ids where not included in the sales table.

**sale table**

sale_id (pk)
product_id (fk)
purchase_id (fk)

**purchase table**

product_id (fk)
purchase_id (pk)

```
SELECT DISTINCT purchase_id
              , product_id
FROM
  purchase
INNER JOIN sale
USING (purchase_id, product_id);
```

Here is an example:
If I run the above code, this will be the result.

```
purchase_id   product id
1             1
1             2
1             4
2             1
2             3
```

Now I want to get:

```
purchase_id   product id
1             3
2             2
```

In short I want to get inverse of above code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your intended output could include {purchase_id=2, product_id=4}, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I understand better now.

This should return any entry in purchase that have no matching entry in sales.

```
SELECT  
  `purchase`.`purchase_id`, `purchase`.`product_id`
FROM `purchase`
  LEFT JOIN `sale` ON `sale`.`purchase_id` = `purchase`.`purchase_id` AND `sale`.`product_id` = `purchase`.`product_id`
WHERE 
  `sale`.`sale_id` IS NULL
ORDER BY 
  `purchase`.`purchase_id`, `purchase`.`product_id`
```

Comment: Yes this will give me the inverse. but problem is, this returned values that haven't exist in purchase table. for a example purchase_id 1 have only 4 product(1,2,3,4). but this will give all combinations of the products that not included in sales table and (pur1,pro5),(pur1,pro6),(pur1,pro9)....

Comment: @ms48mail I thought that is what you wanted. In your post, you mention having 1-1, 1-2, 1-4 in your table but returning 1-3, and 2-1, 2-3 returning 2-2. What is the logic in here? It looks like all missing products where product_id is lesser than the max product_id in sale for that purchase?

Comment: sorry for my bad English. What I actually wanted was get all purchases numbers and product numbers where not involved to make a sale. but your example gave me product ids that not involved in purchases. this I have purchase (pur1,pro1),(pur1,pro3) and sold (pur1,pro1). now I want to get (pur1,pro3). but your example gave me (pur1,pur2). hope you understood.

Comment: @ms48mail Okay, that makes more sense. I think. Can you see if my edit works for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all the purchases that have no related values in the sales table, you can use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select 
    p.purchase_id
from 
    purchase as p
    left join sale as s on p.purchase_id = s.purchase_id
where
    s.purchase_id is null;
```

"Unilateral" joins (`LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`) are useful when you want to get data from a table even if data in another related table does not exist. Of course, that means that you can filter data from one table when there's no related data in a second table.

Hope this helps.

---

Looking at your updated question and your comment, I think that you want all the possible combinations not used.

You'll need to split this in two steps:

1. First you need all the possible combinations of `purchase_id` and `sale_id` values (the "cartesian product" of both the sets).
2. Then you need to get all the combinations already used.
3. Finally you need to exclude all the combinations already used.

This can be done using subqueries.

**Step 1.**

```
select distinct p.purchase_id, s.product_id from purchase as p, sale as s;
```

**Step 2.** (Your query)

```
select distinct 
    purchase_id, product_id 
from 
    purchase as p 
    inner join sale as s 
        on (p.purchase_id = s.purchase_id and p.product_id = s.product_id);
```

**Step 3.** Put it all together

```
select 
    a.*
from
    (select distinct p.purchase_id, s.product_id from purchase as p, sale as s) as a
    left join (
        select distinct 
            purchase_id, product_id 
        from 
            purchase as p 
            inner join sale as s 
                on (p.purchase_id = s.purchase_id and p.product_id = s.product_id)
    ) as e on (a.purchase_id = e.purchase_id and a.product_id = e.product_id)
where
    e.purchase_id is null and e.product_id is null;
```

Comment: hi thanks for the quick reply. I have already tried this method. but it will ignore whole purchase id. for example if I have make sale purchase id=1 product=1 and not used purchase id=1 product id=4,this will omit the 2nd one too.

Comment: @ms48mail I've updated my answer... I think it will help you now

Comment: hey thanks again. but this was gave me that not having recodes in neither purchase table or sales table. for a example. it gave me, purchase_id=1 and product_id=6, purchase_id=1 and product_id=7